# Testing PictureBox in white

Tags: .net, winforms, testing, white-framework

I am currently evaluating the White testing framework. Pretty amazing stuff!

Everything looks pretty promising, but I have run into a small wall.

How can I test a .NET 2.0 PictureBox?

There is no predefinied UIItem for that. Though there is the Image class, but how would I use it in combination with my PictureBox?

I also tried to use a CustomUIItem, but with no success. How would I implement this for a my standard PictureBox?

What are my options? What did I miss?

Thanks

Just to clearify:

 I know that something like this should be tested in code. Believe me I know. But unfortunately this ui automation is a requirement, unfortuanetly...

Now I just need a way to maybe get the image location or something. Just like I am able to get the text in any WinForms TextBox.

Update:

This is a dump of the Debug.Details for my Window. I hope this helps to understand and hopefully even solve my problem.

```
---------------------------
---------------------------
AutomationId: Form1
ControlType: ControlType.Window
Name: Form1
HelpText: 
Bounding rectangle: 154;203;680;490
ClassName: WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.378734a
IsOffScreen: False
    AutomationId: progressBar1
    ControlType: ControlType.ProgressBar
    Name: 
    HelpText: 
    Bounding rectangle: 198;488;190;23
    ClassName: WindowsForms10.msctls_progress32.app.0.378734a
    IsOffScreen: False
    AutomationId: Progress
    ControlType: ControlType.Button
    Name: Start Progress
    HelpText: 
    Bounding rectangle: 198;459;190;23
    ClassName: WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.378734a
    IsOffScreen: False
    AutomationId: PicBox
    ControlType: ControlType.Pane
    Name: 
    HelpText: 
    Bounding rectangle: 619;274;199;140
    ClassName: WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.378734a
    IsOffScreen: False
    AutomationId: PicCombo
    ControlType: ControlType.ComboBox
    Name: 
    HelpText: 
    Bounding rectangle: 619;247;199;21
    ClassName: WindowsForms10.COMBOBOX.app.0.378734a
    IsOffScreen: False
        AutomationId: 1001
        ControlType: ControlType.Edit
        Name: 
        HelpText: 
        Bounding rectangle: 622;250;176;15
        ClassName: Edit
        IsOffScreen: False
        AutomationId: ListBox
        ControlType: ControlType.List
        Name: 
        HelpText: 
        Bounding rectangle: 0;21;199;41
        ClassName: ComboLBox
        IsOffScreen: True
            AutomationId: 
            ControlType: ControlType.ListItem
            Name: **********
            HelpText: 
            Bounding rectangle: 1;22;197;13
            ClassName: 
            IsOffScreen: True
            AutomationId: 
            ControlType: ControlType.ListItem
            Name: **********
            HelpText: 
            Bounding rectangle: 1;35;197;13
            ClassName: 
            IsOffScreen: True
            AutomationId: 
            ControlType: ControlType.ListItem
            Name: **********
            HelpText: 
            Bounding rectangle: 1;48;197;13
            ClassName: 
            IsOffScreen: True
        AutomationId: DropDown
        ControlType: ControlType.Button
        Name: Dropdown-Schaltfläche
        HelpText: 
        Bounding rectangle: 800;248;17;19
        ClassName: 
        IsOffScreen: False
    AutomationId: EditRadio
    ControlType: ControlType.RadioButton
    Name: Edit
    HelpText: 
    Bounding rectangle: 198;420;43;17
    ClassName: WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.378734a
    IsOffScreen: False
    AutomationId: ComboRadio
    ControlType: ControlType.RadioButton
    Name: Combo
    HelpText: 
    Bounding rectangle: 198;397;58;17
    ClassName: WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.378734a
    IsOffScreen: False
    AutomationId: tb1
    ControlType: ControlType.Edit
    Name: 
    HelpText: 
    Bounding rectangle: 198;303;190;20
    ClassName: WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.378734a
    IsOffScreen: False
    AutomationId: btn2
    ControlType: ControlType.Button
    Name: button1
    HelpText: 
    Bounding rectangle: 198;274;190;23
    ClassName: WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.378734a
    IsOffScreen: False
    AutomationId: btn1
    ControlType: ControlType.Button
    Name: button1
    HelpText: 
    Bounding rectangle: 198;245;190;23
    ClassName: WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.378734a
    IsOffScreen: False
    AutomationId: TitleBar
    ControlType: ControlType.TitleBar
    Name: Form1
    HelpText: 
    Bounding rectangle: 158;207;672;26
    ClassName: 
    IsOffScreen: False
        AutomationId: Form1
        ControlType: ControlType.MenuBar
        Name: Systemmenüleiste
        HelpText: 
        Bounding rectangle: 158;207;18;25
        ClassName: 
        IsOffScreen: False
            AutomationId: Item 1
            ControlType: ControlType.MenuItem
            Name: System
            HelpText: 
            Bounding rectangle: 158;207;18;25
            ClassName: 
            IsOffScreen: False
        AutomationId: Minimize
        ControlType: ControlType.Button
        Name: Minimieren
        HelpText: 
        Bounding rectangle: 758;207;24;24
        ClassName: 
        IsOffScreen: False
        AutomationId: Maximize
        ControlType: ControlType.Button
        Name: Maximieren
        HelpText: 
        Bounding rectangle: 782;207;24;24
        ClassName: 
        IsOffScreen: False
        AutomationId: Close
        ControlType: ControlType.Button
        Name: Schließen
        HelpText: 
        Bounding rectangle: 806;207;24;24
        ClassName: 
        IsOffScreen: False
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score -3):

So what exactly are you trying to test?

I am sure MS has tested the controls in the Framework already, and should not require further user testing, unless you dont trust the Framework...

Comment: I want to test my own code. Its just for evaluation. I want to automate WinForms. The image retrieval is a non-trivial task. And I now want to test if the correct image is displayed in my PictureBox. I know I probably could just test this in code. But unfortuanetly, "the visual route", is a requirement. I would have done it differently aswell...

Comment: So how will you test a visual appearance? I dont think that is very possible unless you compare it to screenshots or something.

Comment: No just the path to the image or something. Just Like TextBox.Text I want to be able to get PictureBox.Image